# fragments = title + webView + actionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I found this project: i wan't to do a similar thing.
I want to know if there is an open source project (similar to this one).

And more details on how i can do this?

Thanks

[image: LinearFragment]

here are the project: 
http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/02/android-app-surgery-earthquake-redux.html

Comment: "And more details on how i can do this?" More details on how you can do what?

Comment: I am just taking my first look at android 3.0 and I can't find a Fragments example that I can just put into Eclipse and have it run. I usually learn quicker if I have a basic example in front of me that I can play with, and screw up, and learn from etc.

Comment: I posted an answer with links to fragment examples provided by google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the android developers site, there are several examples using `Fragments`.

[Check these out and see if it helps.](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Fragment)

Comment: i have seen this examples, it is very sample i want a combination between more than three fragments and with map view in a fragment if possible
thanks